# Find images of a specific size and move them to trash from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

Im sorting images in a kinda large image library, and thumbnails from old iPhoto-library is still in there. And I'm in need of removing them to improve speed of sorting the images.

I have found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/239150) answer here for linux, but how about macOS? Is there a way of searching a folder, recursively, and determine if the image `*.jpg, *.png, *.bmp, *.jpeg` have the W360 and H270?

Running Sierra 10.12.4

Comment: You could install `imagemagick` or fashion an algorithm using `mdls`. Something like `mdls -raw -name kMDItemPixelWidth file` would get you the width of the image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example `bash` *script* that can achieve the goal natively, no need to install anything.

```
#!/bin/bash

targetDir="$HOME/Pictures"

find "$targetDir" -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.bmp' -o -iname '*.jpeg' 2>/dev/null | \
while read -r filename; do
    hw="$(sips -g pixelHeight -g pixelWidth "$filename" 2>/dev/null)"
    h="$(awk '/pixelHeight/{print $2}'<<<"$hw")"
    w="$(awk '/pixelWidth/{print $2}'<<<"$hw")"
    if [[ $h -eq 270 ]] && [[ $w -eq 360 ]]; then
        echo rm "$filename"
    fi
done
```

All you need to do is set the `targetDir` *variable* to the starting point of where you want the `find` *command* to look. The default is the Pictures folder within your Home folder.

**Note:** In the example *script* the `echo` *command* needs to be removed from in front of
 `rm "$filename"` in order for the *files* to actually be deleted and is there so you can first test the output of the *script* as to what *files* will be deleted. You can of course choose to remove it without testing and just go for it, if you're confident that you want to delete any .jpg, .png, .bmp or .jpeg file with dimensions of 270 pixel height by 360 pixel width within the `targetDir`.

Also note that depending on the total file count of the target file extensions, the running of this *script* can take some amount of time to complete. On my system it found ~1000 files to delete out of 27500 files in my Pictures folder and took at least 5 to 10 minutes to complete.

That said, I ran this script, as it's written, and the only files other then the test file I created with the target dimensions, all other files found where in one specific location within my iPhoto Library bundle in the Thumbnails folder. So, wouldn't it just be easier to go into the bundle and delete the contents in Finder? That is, if it's really just those Thumbnails you want to get rid of!

---

If you don't know how to use the *script*, do the following in Terminal:

```
touch delete270x360images
open delete270x360images
```

Copy and paste the *script code* from above into the opened `delete270x360images` document, modify as needed/wanted and then save and close.

In Terminal, make it executable:

```
chmod u+x delete270x360images
```

Now to use it in Terminal, type the following and then press enter.

```
./delete270x360images
```

Wait for it to complete.